# How do you read the MajorUnit parameter for an Access chart

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 application that generates a bar chart in VBA.  The spacing between vertical grid lines is controlled by the Axis.MajorUnit parameter.  Normally I am happy to let access automatically set this parameter.  The exception is when Access sets it to less than one.  In that case I would like to override it and force it to one.

Here is the code I tried:

```
If Me.brandHistogram.Axes(1).MajorUnit < 1 Then
    Me.brandHistogram.Axes(1).MajorUnit = 1
End If
```

The problem is that the MajorUnit property seems to be write-only.  Therefore the code fails at the first line.

Any thoughts?

(Access 2010, Windows 7)

Comment: In what event are you calling this code? [THIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/16ae2a4b-7c2f-4337-89ce-8c36b5102414/ms-access-change-graph-propery-majorunit-with-vba?forum=accessdev) suggests you should do it in the `Detail_Format` event.

Comment: I am doing this within the form module (Form_FormName).  The code is triggered whenever the user changes a value in an unbound control on the form.  Your idea of doing it as a reaction to chart event is interesting ... I will give it a try.